# How to Reset Password for User with Unverified (and possibly incorrect) Email on Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, passwords, forgot-password, password-recovery, email-verification

When a user initially signs up through my app on Parse.com, they supply a username, an email address, and a password.

They verify that email address before they can start using the Parse.com functionalities. So now the user has a valid username, email address and password.

Then, consider this scenario:

1) The user changes his or her email address. 2) The user fails to validate the new email address. 3) The user doesn't use the app for a while. 4) The user forgets his or her password. 5) The user asks to reset the password.

If the user used his or her old email address for the password reset, that address is now gone and the user won't be able to reset the password using that email address.

If the user used the new email address, that address is not verified. Furthermore, it might not have been verified because it could have been typed in wrongly. So the user won't be able to reset the password using that email address.

How is this supposed to have gone down? Is there any way to keep the old email address until the new email address has been verified? That is the only way I can see that this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the Trigger features from Parse CloudCode?

https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers

Here you can perform code before or after some Object changing. So you can do what you suggested in the bottom of your question: save in another field de old email when the email or emailVerified fields changes.

Comment: If the old email is in another field, how can it actually be useful? It seems like this has not been thought through at all by Parse... Is there any way to keep the old email address *as the actual email address* until the new email address has been verified? Thanks for commenting, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @SAHM why don't you give a custom support for this cases?

Comment: What is a custom support?

Comment: Something like your user contacting you by email and you fixing this issue directly in the Parse Browser. =]

Comment: Umm, ok. Just seems like this whole thing is such awful, awful design. Like Parse didn't think through *anything*. Plus, it is impossible to get any help from Parse. Just terrible that I have to build "contacting me" into the plan with Parse. Should never happen.

Comment: What is the best alternative to Parse? I need something solid and professional.